# How to round REAL type to NUMERIC?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, types, plpgsql, postgresql-8.3

I have table with `real` column type with example values:

```
123456,12
0,12345678
```

And code in stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test3()
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
   DECLARE
      rec    RECORD;
   BEGIN

      FOR rec IN 

         SELECT
         gme.abs_km as km,
         CAST(gme.abs_km as numeric) as cast,         
         round(gme.abs_km:: numeric(16,2), 2) as round
         FROM gps_entry gme
      LOOP

         RAISE NOTICE 'Km: % , cast: % , round: %', rec.km, rec.cast, rec.round;
         INSERT INTO test (km, casting, rounding) VALUES (rec.km, rec.cast, rec.round);

      END LOOP;
      RETURN 1;      
   END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Here is output:

```
2014-02-05 12:49:53 CET NOTICE:  Km: 0.12345678 , cast: 0.123457 , round: 0.12
2014-02-05 12:49:53 CET NOTICE:  Km: 123456.12 , cast: 123456 , round: 123456.00
```

DB table with columns `NUMERIC(19,2)`:

```
km        casting   rounding
0.12      0.12      0.12

123456.00 123456.00 123456.00
```

Why do `cast` and `round` functions not work for the value `123456.12`?

Comment: To format numbers for display to the user, use `to_char`.

Comment: actually I would like to insert these values to db table with columns numeric(19,2), I have updated code in question

Comment: Issue seems to be with numbers that have more than 6 digits, for these numbers casting and rounding works: 1.23  1234.12, 123.456

Answer (score 5):

[**`real`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) is a lossy, inexact floating-point type. It only uses 4 bytes for storage and may not store the presented numeric literals precisely to begin with. In addition, implementation details depend on your platform. Consider [the chapter "Floating-Point Types" in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT)

There is nothing wrong with either `round()` or `cast()`. For (more) exact results, use [`numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).

#### Function audit

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test3()
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r record;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN 
      SELECT abs_km AS km
           , cast(abs_km AS numeric) AS km_cast
           , round(abs_km::numeric, 2) AS km_round
      FROM   gps_entry
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'km: % , km_cast: % , km_round: %'
                  , r.km, r.km_cast, r.km_round;
      INSERT INTO test (km, casting, rounding)
      VALUES (r.km, r.km_cast, r.km_round);
   END LOOP;    
END
$func$;
```

Of course, it would be more efficient to replace the loop with a single multi-row `INSERT` statement.

Do not quote the language name `plpgsql`. It's an identifier.

Makes no sense to round to 2 fractional digits *after* casting to `numeric(16,2)`, which forcibly rounds already. Either / or ..

```
round(abs_km:: numeric(16,2), 2) as round
round(abs_km::numeric, 2) as round
abs_km::numeric(16,2) as round
```