# Why are my PostgreSQL "real" data being rounded?

Tags: postgresql, precision, postgresql-11

I have a table with a column named `total` having the `real` data type.

But I'm finding that this column is being rounded when I query its value, as illustrated in the following:

```
SELECT total FROM data WHERE id='xe54g';
 total 
---------
  105861

UPDATE data SET total=105860.5 WHERE id='xe54g';        
UPDATE 1

SELECT total FROM data WHERE id='xe54g';
 total 
---------
  105860

UPDATE data SET total=105860.7 WHERE id='xe54g';        
UPDATE 1

SELECT total FROM data WHERE id='xe54g';
 total 
---------
  105861

\d+ data
   Column  |  Type | Collation | Nullable |  Default  | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------+-------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 total     | real  |           |          | 0         | plain    |              |
```

How do I get it to return the full precision?  I'm using PG 11.1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21586899/784648 Similar post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round REAL type to NUMERIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576685/how-to-round-real-type-to-numeric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the full precision by setting

```
extra_float_digits = 3
```

Then PostgreSQL will also display decimal digits that may contain rounding errors.

Note that `real` has a low number of significant digits. You'd be happier if you used `double precision`.

Comment: Aah, I see that `real` has a 6 decimal digits precision.  The numbers I'm using are already 6 digits without the decimal places, and hence the issue.  It works OK for e.g. `SET total=90586.7`.  Can I safely convert my `real` column to `double precision`?

Comment: Yes, but it may take a while for a big table, because the table has to be rewritten. `double precision`takes 8 bytes, while `real`only uses 4.

Comment: OK thanks.  Is this the correct way to convert: `ALTER TABLE data ALTER COLUMN total TYPE double precision;` ?

Comment: why not using `decimal` datatype instead? as it is a exact datatype.. `double precision` is still inexact or approximate, @drmrbrewer i would advice using `decimal` datatype especially when you are dealing with money or other totals it has to be exact

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks, will consider that.  Again, assume it's safe to convert the column data type from `real` or `double precision` to `decimal` with e.g. `ALTER TABLE data ALTER COLUMN total TYPE decimal;` ?

Comment: almost correct @drmrbrewer but decimals need to defined like `decimal(4, 2)` for example it depends what you need, the 4 are the number before the comma  and 2 are the number after so `decimal(4, 2)` stores the max off `9999.99`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I thought the docs say that you can just specify `decimal` (or `numeric`) without limit?  Whilst I'm happy to limit `scale` (decimal places) to `1` I don't want to limit overall `precision` (significant figures).  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL : "without any precision or scale creates a column in which numeric values of any precision and scale can be stored"

Comment: Yes, you can use `decimal` (the same as `numeric`) without a type modifier. Use that data type if you need precision and `double precision` if you need speed.

Comment: yes sorry for the confusion @drmrbrewer not sure why i was thinking and making the comment that `decimal(4, 2)` was required for decimal blame it to the leak of caffine or i might be reading to much ANSI/ISO standards documents about SQL where they are required.for decimal datatype