# Calculate ratio of counts in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

I have a table `mydata` in a Postgres 14 database, with the following relevant columns:

- `ftype`: an `enum` having `foo`, `bar` and `baz`
- `status`: another `enum` having `pending`, `failed`, `success`

I want the success rate of different types. Success rate is basically: the number of rows where the `status` is `success` divided by total number of rows for that `ftype`.

Currently, I'm doing the following:

```sql
SELECT
    COALESCE(
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ftype = 'foo' AND status = 'success' THEN 1 END) / 
        NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN ftype = 'foo' THEN 1 END)::real, 0)
    ,0)::real AS foo_rate,

    COALESCE(
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ftype = 'bar' AND status = 'success' THEN 1 END) / 
        NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN ftype = 'bar' THEN 1 END)::real, 0)
    ,0)::real AS bar_rate,

    COALESCE(
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ftype = 'baz' AND status = 'success' THEN 1 END) / 
        NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN ftype = 'baz' THEN 1 END)::real, 0)
    ,0)::real AS baz_rate,
FROM mydata;
```

Is there a better/more performant way? How can I optimize it?
Would using [`PARTITION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-partitioning.html) in the query help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are computing rates for all types, a pivoted result would be simpler:

```sql
SELECT ftype, CASE WHEN ct_success = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ct_success/ct_total END AS rate
FROM  (
   SELECT ftype
        , count(*) AS ct_total
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'success')::real AS ct_success
   FROM   mydata
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub;
```

Works for a selection of types, too. (The benefit is smaller, though.) Filter early:

```sql
SELECT ftype, CASE WHEN ct_success = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ct_success/ct_total END AS rate
FROM  (
   SELECT ftype
        , count(*) AS ct_total
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 'success')::real AS ct_success
   FROM   mydata
   WHERE  ftype = ANY ('{foo,bar,baz}'::my_enum_type[])  -- here!
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub;
```

About the `WHERE` clause:

- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)

You may want to `round()` and/or use `numeric` to begin with. See:

- [How to round REAL type to NUMERIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576685/how-to-round-real-type-to-numeric/21586899#21586899)
- [Rounding of the numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385131/rounding-of-the-numeric-values/29386280#29386280)

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Whether [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) might help is hard to tell from the minimal information we have. There are useful guidelines in the manual chapter ["Overview"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-OVERVIEW) for "Table Partitioning". My educated guess is that it wouldn't benefit you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems simpler. Was not aware of `FILTER`. 

If I want the results only for certain types, I can add a `WHERE` clause in the end, or is there some other way? I ask this because you started your answer with: 

>  Since you are computing rates for all types

Comment: @Abhijit: I added a bit above.